# Do German shopping malls offer staffed children playrooms?

Tags: germany, children, shopping

In Russia, in many shopping malls, especially the biggest ones, there is a playroom, where parents can leave their children. The children will play there and will be looked after by the playroom staff, allowing the parent to do shopping. Of course this is for a relatively small fee (like €5-10 per hour).

A year ago I was in Germany in Munich, and I saw nothing of that kind; now I am in Berlin and apparently there is nothing like this too. Do such playrooms not exist indeed in Germany, or I just did not happen to find them? If they are really uncommon, is the situation the same in the rest of Europe?

Comment: I've never come across one of these during my Europe travels, and they are certainly not a common/normal thing to exist in the UK

Comment: Many of the larger malls in the UK have children's play areas eg https://blog.picniq.co.uk/play-centres-in-shopping-centres/ but AFAIK not all offer supervised play without the parents being present

Comment: When I was small they were more common in the uk (generally referred to as a creche) but in the intervening decades they have mostly disappeared

Comment: Can you clarify how inclusive you define *mall?* In my whole life in Germany, I have only ever visited three establishments that I would call *mall* (everything else is just a supermarket plus a few satellite stores, such as a bakery, pharmacy, or hairdresser). One of them has what you describe, but that’s not much of a statistics.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, well, I mean any big establishments with a very wide assortment of goods from grocery to clothing to houseware to toys to electronics etc. Today we've been to The mall of Berlin, also I've looked on Potsdamer platz arkaden and KaDeWe websites (this is what google search for "berlin mall" found). In Munich past year we've been in Karstadt (well, a single big store, not different stores, but still a wide assortment) and also some other place that I do not remember.

Comment: In malls they’re indeed rare I’d say, though one place that comes to mind is “Porta”, a furniture chain probably modeled after IKEA in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I lived the most part of my life in Germany, though the last ten years I haven't. I don't remember seeing these anywhere other than IKEA and maybe some other, really large stores, but not malls (malls are generally not that prevalent anyway there).

If interested in a particular mall, try googling something like `mallname Kinderbetreuung` or generically `cityname Einkaufszentrum Kinderbetreuung`. There do seem to be quite a few hits.

Answer (score 7):

I can't speak for the whole of Europe, but these are certainly not common in Germany. I don't remember them in the UK either, although it's a while (8 years) since I lived there.

IKEA stores quite often have them (with limited opening hours), but that's the only example I can remember seeing.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes more common in the last time. Especially big malls or shops with a big catchment area add this to their services.

From own experience I know "IKEA" and "[Möbel Gruber](https://www.moebel-gruber.de/service/kinderland/)" (in the category "big shop") and "[West Park](https://westpark-center.de/Services)" (see "Paradies")  (in the category "shopping mall") to have staffed children's playrooms.